# How do I make Illustrator export for screens at <0.5x?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

Does anyone have a method by which I can export in Illustrator at <0.5x? It seems -- unlike Photoshop -- if I attempt to export @0.33x, say, Illustrator automatically and infuriatingly brings the export target to @0.5x.

Comment: Hello Michael. I'm sorry to tell you that we are not Adobe, just a group of volunteers asking and answering Graphic Design questions. Therefore, I edited your rant out of your question, for it is not the right place here. If you could [edit] your question to include an example of your attempts, we could try to help you. Thanks for understanding. If you want to know more about Graphic Design Stack Exchange, please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help], they should get you up to speed. Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator does not allow you scale at other percentages.

If all your artboards are the same size, you could take the artboard size and divide by the percentage you want. Then change the scale to width and write down the width that you just calculated.

Ex. Artboard size is 580px and you want .33x, you would change the scale to width and write 191px.